# How to remove Android vitals ANR and Crash rate in Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-vitals

I have an android app build in flutter framework. ANR and crash rates are high. My app users are complaining about these errors.
How to get rid of these errors?

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem, are you using webviews in your app?